# Vector of Vector with custom class

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to teach myself C++ and found an example problem online oriented around a soda inventory.  I have two classes 1) inventory and 2) soda.  Soda contains its initial amount (int), name (string), id (string), and quantity (int).  Inventory contains a vector of vectors (of type soda).

Class declaration for inventory:

```
private:
std::vector< std::vector<Soda> > softDrinks;
public:
Inventory();
void buildInventoryGood();
void processTransactionsGood();
std::string displayReport();
```

Class declaration for soda:

```
private:
std::string name;
std::string id;
int quantity;
int startingAmount;
int numberOfTransactions;

public:
Soda();
Soda(std::string sodaName, std::string sodaID, int initialAmount);
int addSoda(std::string id, int amount);
int withdrawSoda(std::string id, int toWithdraw);
std::string Report();
std::string getName();
std::string getID();
```

I can run buildInventoryGood() and it builds everything fine.  (below is the result if I were to cout a report)

```
Name    ID      InitialAmount   FinalAmount
coke    123     100             300
pepsi   321     200             200
Shasta  987     300             300
```

My problem is with processTransactionGood().  I've left some cout debug statements in there to help me figure out what is going on.

```
void Inventory::processTransactionsGood()
{
vector<Soda> vecSoda;
string textline;
string name;
string id;
int quantity;
ifstream infile("data6trans.txt");

while (getline(infile, textline))
{
    string space_string;
    std::istringstream text_stream(textline);
    text_stream >> id;
    getline(text_stream, space_string, ' '); // Read characters after number until space.
    text_stream >> quantity;

    for (auto drink : softDrinks) {
        auto it = find_if(drink.begin(), drink.end(), [id](Soda obj) {return obj.getID() == id; });
        if (it == drink.end()) {}
        else {
            auto index = distance(drink.begin(), it);
            cout << id << "  " << quantity << " " << index << "a" << endl;
            drink[index].withdrawSoda(id, quantity);
            cout << drink[index].Report() << endl;
        }
    }
}
}
```

That last cout statement shows me that a given soda was processed (in this instance decremented by a value of one)

```
Name    Id      starting        final
Shasta  987     300             299
```

The final result for Shasta should be 299.
But when I run displayReport() I get a result I wasn't expecting:

```
string Inventory::displayReport() 
{
string report = "Name\tID\tInitialAmount\tFinalAmount\n";
for (auto item : softDrinks) {
    for (auto drink : item) {
        report += drink.Report();
    }
}
return report;
}
```

I get:

```
Name    ID      InitialAmount   FinalAmount
coke    123     100             300
pepsi   321     200             200
Shasta  987     300             300
```

All that to say: I'm not sure that I'm grasping the practice of a vector of vectors and I'm not setting something the way it should be
Edit: ^ and I don't know what the right way is and am looking for a pointer or reference.

Comment: The worst part of all this code is that you would dare leave Shasta capitalized, but not Pepsi nor Coke.

Comment: one must first be able to master the ability to add and subtract correctly before they start to do user input validation and string manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (auto drink : softDrinks)
```

makes `drink` to be a **copy** of `softDrink`'s element. That's why the modified element isn't stored to `softDrinks`.

Please use

```
for (auto &drink : softDrinks)
```

instead of that to have a reference in hand.

Comment: AndreyS thanks.  That fixed it perfectly.  I guess I need to re-read about & and *.

Comment: You're welcome :) It's a really confusing point in C++11 as we believe 'auto' makes all things right for us - and this is on top of the 'traditional' confusion about copy vs. reference.

Comment: @lunchbox, you may find [this article](https://swdevmastery.com/dont-use-c-auto-restricting-auto-is-not-the-best-decision-for-your-company-and-it-is-unfair-to-your-developers-instead-train-them-on-how-to-use-it/) I wrote useful. It summarizes auto type deduction rules.